# an icon who goes out the screen when i resize the browser

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i have problem witn an icon (Loop icon) who goes out the screen when i resize the browser and that's create a white margin left , i'm using bootstrap and less , i i putted a [Link](http://revue-esiea.fr/) to the page for you to see my problem and this is the code too

HTML

```
<body>

    <header class="top-header">

        <div class="container">

            <div class="row">

                <div class="span6">
                    <h1 class="logo">
                        <a href="#" class="hide-text">Caspevi</a>
                    </h1>
                    <h2>Le Moteur de recherche</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="span6"></div>

            </div>

        </div>  
        <!-- end container  -->

    </header> 



    <!-- Recherche générale    -->

    <section>

        <div class="section-form1">

            <div class="container">


                <form action"/" method="post" class="genaral-form">

                    <p class="contour">

                        <a href="#"></a> 

                    </p>


                </form>



            </div>

        </div>


    </section>

    <!-- recherche personaliser  -->



</body>
```

CSS

```
.section-form1 {
    background: url('../image/background_top.png') no-repeat center;
    background-color: #000;
    width: 100%;
        height: 694px;

    a {
        background: url('../image/forme_serche.png');
        width: 61px;
        height: 61px;
        position: absolute;
        top: -40px;
        left: 413px;
        &:hover {
        background: url('../image/forme_serche_hover.png');
        }
    }

}





.contour {
    position: relative;
    height: 239px;
    border: 1px solid white;
       -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
       -moz-border-radius: 4px;
        border-radius: 4px;
        margin-left: 120px;
        margin-right: 120px;
    margin-top: 80px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I advise that you need to change the position from absolute to relative. You can then use a float:left and a width-margin that is a percentage.

Answer (score 0):

You have just to replace this line. The absolute position have to be from right :

```
.section-form1 a {
...
left: 413px;
}
```

by

```
.section-form1 a {
...
right: -27px;
}
```

Regards

Comment: same problem but this time it appears on the top right corner of the border and when i try to position it to the midle of the border and i resize the the browser it goes out of the screen !!

Answer (score 0):

Like the above answer, it is just problem with position: absolute. I would recommend you to not use position: "absolute" or "fixed" just in special cases. You will have a lot of problems with responsive/fluid designs.